# NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'book-detail' not found. 'book-detail' is not a valid view function or pattern name

Tags: python, django

Такая проблема: повторял код с книги и дошел до момента, где надо было указать ссылку на страницу, которая загружает список данных с БД. При переходе получаю вот такую ошибку:

> django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'book-detail' not found. 'book-detail' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

Так же показывает на вот эту строчку:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```html
{% extends "base_generic.html" %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>Список книг в БД</h1>
    {% if book_list %}
    <ul>
        {% for book in book_list %}
        <li>
            <a href="{{ book.get_absolute_url }}">{{ book.title }}</a>
            ({{book.genre}})
        </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    {% else %}
        <p>В базе данных нет книг</p>
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Мне не очень понятно почему, так, единственное может быть то что вместо urls, я указал path. Поставить urls не мог, так как в библиотеки его убрали.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, re_path
from catalog import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path(r'^books/$', views.BookListView.as_view(), name='books'),
]
```

Так же не знаю, может ругается на модель в которой есть один метод:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```py
def get_absolute_url(self):
    # Возвращает URL-адрес для доступа к определенному экземпляру книги.
    return reverse('book-detail', args=[str(self.id)])
```

Может кто подсказать как решить эту проблему?

P.S. Добавлен код с картинок.

После добавления в urls.py:

```
path('book-detail/', views.BookDetailView.as_view(), name='book-detail'),
```

А также класс BookDetailView в файле views.py:

```
class BookDetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Book
```

Я получил новую ошибку:

> NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'book-detail' with arguments '('1',)' not
> found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['book\-detail/\Z']

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Добавьте код текстом, не картинками.

Comment: @JackOwest добавил код. Вы знаете как решить мою проблему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вам надо передать id конкретной книги

```
path('book-detail/<int:pk>', views.BookDetailView.as_view(), name='book-detail'),
```

Answer (score 1):

Вам не хватает пути к book-detail.

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path(r'^books/$', views.BookListView.as_view(), name='books'),
    path('book-detail/', views.BookDetailView.as_view(), name='book-detail'),
]
```

Comment: К сожалению нет. Это не помогло. Выдало ошибку 'AttributeError: module 'catalog.views' has no attribute 'BookDetailView''
Может что-то другое?

Comment: Может вы сталкивались то что выдало мне новую ошибку?